# OpenAI Gym Atari Baseline deepq train.py fails

Tags: python-3.x, openai-gym

I was trying to train the Atari 2600 game Frostbite on **OpenAI's DQN** Baseline. I'm using Linux and Python 3. After spending some time trying to run it I noticed a couple issues:

1. `from baselines.common.atari_wrappers_deprecated import wrap_dqn`
   Was not being recognized. After searching online I found that this was a quick fix:
   `from baselines.common.atari_wrappers import wrap_deepmind`
2. When I ran the code after that I get the following error in line 246 of experiments/atari/train.py:

> start_time, start_steps = time.time(), info["steps"] KeyError: 'steps'

I noticed a couple other people had this issue pop up within the last 15 days or so and there have been no responses yet. I'm new to RL so don't have much of an idea. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Same problem.  Looked at a few other nearby files and it seems the way they use info["steps"] here is done differently elsewhere, so I fixed that.  Then later there's an info["rewards"] which gets the same problem.  It's also done differently elsewhere.  I suspect these train.py and enjoy.py files are out of date.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly large commit "bb40378" that caused this problem, as some things were changed in that commit which broke baselines/deepq/experiments/atari/train.py and enjoy.py.  I got them working with the following steps:

1. Replace baselines/common/misc_util.py with the version from commit "8822518".  All that happened in commit "bb40378" was deletion of SimpleMonitor which sets those necessary keys "steps" and "rewards" that train.py needs, so getting the old version gets that back.
2. Modify train.py to import that SimpleMonitor and use it, and to fix that env wrapper problem (wrap_atari_dqn is the correct one I believe)

I forked their repository for this fix.  You can see the commit [here.](https://github.com/jpangburn/baselines/commit/a9fbb5549156577d8f70b66571ed8f61142e0f7e)
 So you can choose to make those changes to your own clone of their repo, or just clone my repo as you prefer.

While I was at it, I put in an option on enjoy.py to display the observation as shown to the model (so you can see if scaling or grayscale transform lost critical info for a game).

## Update

It is probably worth pointing out that I've tried this thing on Pong and Breakout with little success.  With Breakout it just goes and sits on the far left side of the screen- as the serve always seems to be over there it inevitably gets some points but it's not really playing.  With Pong it just goes to the bottom of the screen and sits there.  So at least the default learning stuff under this experiments/atari doesn't really seem to learn atari stuff too well, probably there's some settings that needs to be changed and it'll take off but be warned it's not going to amaze and stupefy your friends out of the box.